# How to set and get using model in Hashmap?

Tags: android, hashmap

Model

```
private HashMap<String, Object> data;

    public Mode() {
        this.data = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    }

    public Object get(Mode value) {
        return this.data.get(value);
    }

    public void set(String key, Object value) {
        this.data.put(key, value);
    }

}
```

How do I set and get the value using this model?

Comment: ???? You literally have a get and a set method

Comment: Y using HashMap, y not Arraylist<Model>

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
public Object get(String key) {
    return this.data.get(key);
}

public void set(String key, Object value) {
    this.data.put(key, value);
}
```

Comment: this is what exactly mentioned in the question

Comment: No it is not. He used `Mode` as a parameter for the key while his hashmap has a key of type `String` so not sure why the downvote. Care to explain? And it seems like the OP used it in his nest question so... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43755775/how-to-set-the-text-view-using-the-data-model-in-hash-map